# angularjs nomod error on the server

Tags: angularjs

I work on an angular rails application

I have installed angular-ui-select and angular-bootstrap-toggle with bower

```
"angular-ui-select": "latest",
"angular-bootstrap-toggle": "latest"
```

Then I am specifing them as dependencies 
    "angular-ui-select": "latest",
    "angular-bootstrap-toggle": "latest"

I require them on the javascript file

```
//= require angular-ui-select
//= require angular-bootstrap-toggle
```

and define them as dependencies on the module

```
var mcApp = angular.module('mcApp', ['ui.select', 'ui.toggle']);
```

All this works fine on my localhost but when I deploy to the server I am getting an Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'mcApp' is not available!

Comment: Does the folders and file structure on the server similar to the development environment? if you try to run the server in development mode?

Comment: verify that you have add `ng-app="mcApp"` in html tag

Comment: did you setup your main page as start up page in IIS?